# Dealing with the Tkinter Text Widgets Indexing System. 

Tags: python, text, indexing, tkinter

How do I split a floating point number.

For example :

1.24345 would return 24345

1455.24 would return 24

1455.0 would return 0

**Edit :**

My solution inspired by Nick ODell. This is oriented specifically toward the Tkinter Text widget.

```
index = '140.2020'

split = index.split('.')

nindex = [int(i) for i in split]

print nindex
```

Comment: What do you do with 1.0/3.0 or 0.29999999999999999 ?

Comment: But that's nonsense. `1455.24` is equal to `1455.2400` or `1455.24000000000`, so why shouldn't the result be `24000000000`?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Please mark homework as homework.

Comment: I'm guessing you've considered casting to string, splitting and back to int and don't like it?

Comment: you mean fractional rather than decimal and the question is pointless

Comment: or what would you do with 0.0002, it would just return 2 whether it was 0.2 or 0.000(... a billion 0s )02

Comment: @RectangleTangle: you should reword your question to make it more clear that the problem has to do with splitting a tkinter text widget index, *not* a floating point number. The index may look like a floating point number but it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that 'index' is a string since you are dealing with a text widget index:

```
int(index.split('.')[-1])
```

If you really do have a floating point number, you need to convert it to a string first:

```
int(str(index).split('.')[-1])
```

Comment: The Tkinter Text widget has an odd indexing system. Lines are represented as the firs half of the floating point. While the decimal portion is represents the amount of of characters in. So 3.74 would be line 3, 74 characters in.

Comment: Good god. I'm sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: @rectangle very hard to believe. What about non representable numbers?

Comment: "line/column indexes are the basic
index type. They are given as strings
consisting of a line number and
column number, separated by a
period." so they are strings not floating point. Answer should read `int(index.split('.')[-1])`

Comment: @RectangleTangle: your explanation isn't quite correct. Tk doesn't return a float, it returns a string of the form line.column'. The fct that it looks like a floating point number isincidental.

Answer (score 5):

[The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

> Note that line/column indexes may look
>   like floating point values, but it’s
>   seldom possible to treat them as such
>   (consider position 1.25 vs. 1.3, for
>   example). I sometimes use 1.0 instead
>   of “1.0” to save a few keystrokes when
>   referring to the first character in
>   the buffer, but that’s about it.

You should have mentioned the context in the OP (Tkinter Text Widget). What you're doing has nothing to do with floating-point numbers at all. You're just finding a period, followed by an integer.  You should never store this value in any floating-point variable. (Doing so could have dire consequences.)

Comment: In retrospect I should have. However, Nick ODell's line combine with my own code seems to be an adequate solution to my problem.

Comment: @RectangleTangle: Nick's code presupposes that `num` is a floating-point variable.  If it is, your code will often fail to reference the correct line and character.  You should only store these values as a pair of integers or as a string.

Comment: @rectangle slow down cowboy! Don't ever convert this string to floating point. Perhaps you aren't even doing so but don't realise that the data is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def after_period(number):
    return int(str(number).partition(".")[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use divmod

```
for num in [1.24345, 1455.24]:   
    whole, dec = divmod(num, 1)   
    print num, whole, dec
```